# Temperature and remanent magnetization

Tags: ferromagnetism

Is it necessary or required to take into account the temperature of the environment whilst determining the remanent field $B_r$ of a magnet? According to the datasheet of the magnet $B_r$ is somewhere in between $1.29-1.32$ T and the maximum operating temperature is at 80 °C.

Comment: Different magnet materials behave differently with temperature. What magnet material are you asking about?

Comment: @Anyone It is a Neodymium magnet

Comment: The temperature should be taken into account since the Br is something that can change due to the temperature history of the magnet. If the magnet was heated to a temperature beyond the operating temperature of the material the residual energy in the magnet will be reduced from when it was initially magnetized.

Comment: @Anyone Ah, thank you. Should have known that. If you submit it as a answer then I will accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temperature should be taken into account since the Br is something that can change due to the temperature history of the magnet. If the magnet was heated to a temperature beyond the operating temperature of the material the residual energy in the magnet will be reduced from when it was initially magnetized.